# Unregistered users and the new profile page

Tags: support, feature-request, profile-page, unregistered-users

In the old profile page it was quite easy to find out if a user is unregistered. It simply said in large letters on the top of the page that the user is not registered.

Is it also easy to spot unregistered users with the new profile page? I've tried to look around, but I couldn't find any indication.

(And before people wonder why, this is useful because sometimes people suggest that a user do something that they cannot do without registration, e.g. vote up, delete, post a question on meta, flag; and it's quite useful to be able to know if these suggestions are moot.)

Comment: As a side note, it seems to me there are a handful of questions that justify having [meta-tag:unregistered-users] around, but I'll wait a couple of days before starting to tag retroactively, just to see if someone thinks differently on this.

Comment: It's not, and I agree this is useful to bring back. Consider submitting it to the [official meta stackexchange question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list) as an answer, with a few words why it's useful? (On both regular and mobile)

Comment: ...actually, someone already did [point this out there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253548/do-the-new-user-pages-no-longer-show-if-a-user-is-unregistered) as a standalone question; so if this matters to you, click the link and upvote only. :)

Comment: If I see a question that I regard as unreasonable, asking far too much of strangers, i check, if the user is unregistered I leave it alone.

Comment: @gnometorule: And if I don't have an account on meta.SE?

Comment: You can just create a meta.SE account associated to your current account... You'll get a welcome 100 rep there (enough to upvote) and with the new profile page, you can hide it from your math.SE profile, if you want.

Comment: @Najib: Obviously. I just don't want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has also been [reported on meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253548/259867) and fixed as of today. The profile  of an unregistered user now looks like this:

[image: profile]

---

(By the way: if you find the "air of mystery" in the above screenshot annoying, see [the discussion at meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251810/the-site-should-not-make-speculative-statements-about-its-users)).

Comment: Air of mystery sounds like a polite way to say "Smell around, and guess what I had for dinner last night?"